# angular2: The hierarchic Json data cannot displayed correctly

Tags: angular

I test the angular2-seed (https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed) for displaying the repo-detail, which is a pure json string, in a table. so appending the following code in repo-detail.component.html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{repoDetails.id}}</td>
        <td>{{repoDetails.owner.login}}</td> <!--It's ok without this line-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the data is not correctly displayed. In the console, i got:

```
zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./RepoDetailComponent class RepoDetailComponent - inline template:7:12 caused by: 
Cannot read property 'login' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError {_nativeError: Error: Error in ./RepoDetailComponent class RepoDetailComponent - inline template:7:12 caused by: Ca…, originalError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_RepoDetailComponent0.…, context: DebugContext} TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_RepoDetailComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/RepoDetailComponent/component.ngfactory.js:108:72)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges
```

...

Comment: It seems that `repoDetails` object doesn't have an `owner` field. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Later i used {{repoDetails?.owner?.login}}, and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<table>
    <tr *ngIf="repoDetails">
        <td>{{repoDetails.id}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="repoDetails.owner">{{repoDetails.owner.login}}</td> <!--It's ok without this line-->
    </tr>
</table>
```

what you are doing here is you are rendering the template only when `repoDetails.owner` is available.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Later i used {{repoDetails?.owner?.login}}, and it solves the problem.